# How to find formula for generic summation n/(n + C)

Tags: sequences-and-series, algorithms

Note:  Completely revised in response to questions/comments on December 23, 2020 at 16:35 UTC.

I'm working on a coding challenge where you have to sum up a series of fractions.  These fractions form a matrix.  For example:

$n=0:\ \ 0$

$n=1:\ \ \frac{1}{2}$

$n=4:$

$\frac{1}{2}\ +\ \frac{2}{3}\ +\ \frac{3}{4}\ +\ \frac{4}{5}$

$\frac{1}{3}\ +\ \frac{2}{4}\ +\ \frac{3}{5}\ +\ \frac{4}{6}$

$\frac{1}{4}\ +\ \frac{2}{5}\ +\ \frac{3}{6}\ +\ \frac{4}{7}$

$\frac{1}{5}\ +\ \frac{2}{6}\ +\ \frac{3}{7}\ +\ \frac{4}{8}$

I started with a brute force approach.  I know this isn't a programming forum, but I'm hoping some simple Python code will illustrate this:

```
from fractions import Fraction

def matrix_sum(n):
    total = Fraction()
    for row_denominator in range(1, n + 1):
        for col_numerator in range(1, n + 1):
            total += Fraction(col_numerator, col_numerator + row_denominator)
    return total

>>> matrix_sum(0)
Fraction(0, 1)

>>> matrix_sum(1)
Fraction(1, 2)

>>> matrix_sum(4)
Fraction(8, 1)

>>> matrix_sum(8)
Fraction(32, 1)
```

However, this doesn't work because the challenge purposefully uses huge numbers and imposes strict time constraints.  The above solution is correct, but way too slow (it's $O(n)^2$ - pretty bad algorithmically).  I even tried converting this to C++ for raw speed.  That fixes the computational speed, but because the numbers are so big, it overflows a 64-bit integer (maximum size for normal C++ integer that I can use in this challenge).  I know there are libraries and compilers have their own 128-bit numbers, but the challenge doesn't allow these.

That led me to think there must be some kind of series/sequence algorithm.  I looked at some series - arithmetic, geometric - but they don't quite work.  Here's how I started approaching this:

$\sum_{i=1}^n {col_i \over (col_i\ +\ row)}$

So this summation is for each row of the matrix.  If I let $n=4$ then I get:

Row 1: $\ \sum_{i=1}^4 {col_i \over (col_i\ +\ 1)} = \frac{1}{2}\ +\ \frac{2}{3}\ +\ \frac{3}{4}\ +\ \frac{4}{5}$

Row 2: $\ \sum_{i=1}^4 {col_i \over (col_i\ +\ 2)} = \frac{1}{3}\ +\ \frac{2}{4}\ +\ \frac{3}{5}\ +\ \frac{4}{6}$

Row 3: $\ \sum_{i=1}^4 {col_i \over (col_i\ +\ 3)} = \frac{1}{4}\ +\ \frac{2}{5}\ +\ \frac{3}{6}\ +\ \frac{4}{7}$

Row 4: $\ \sum_{i=1}^4 {col_i \over (col_i\ +\ 4)} = \frac{1}{5}\ +\ \frac{2}{6}\ +\ \frac{3}{7}\ +\ \frac{4}{8}$

I can then sum up those 4 series.  Would it be better to do these as a double summation that represents the rows too?  I apologize, but I'm rusty with summations.

However, in the process of explaining all this - I see there's a clever solution.  If you look along the diagonals, you'll notice that the fractions add up to one.  So, it appears that the clever answer for this series is the number of squares in the matrix divided by 2.  For example, note that when $n=4$ (16 squares), the answer is 8.

I'm still curious if I was thinking through this the right way.  I do a lot of programming and I think I would be much better off with stronger problem solving using pure mathematics.  Any suggestions on refining the summation/series/sequence, approaching this with matrix math/linear algebra, or otherwise solving this mathematically would be greatly appreciated.

Please let me know if any of this isn't clear and thanks.

--Jim

Comment: Are you sure your limits of summation are error free?

Comment: $\sum_{i=1}^n {n \over (n+C)}$ or $\sum_{i=1}^n {i \over (i+C)}$ ?

Comment: There is a lot of confusion on the sum notation..

Comment: You say that $C$ is constant but later it changes. I don't understand

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I did not misunderstand what you are asking for, it seems you have to evaluate the following $n$ sums:
$$
\begin{equation}
\frac{1}{2} + \frac{2}{3} + \dots + \frac{n}{n+1} \\
\frac{1}{3} + \frac{2}{4} + \dots + \frac{n}{n+2} \\
\vdots \\
\frac{1}{n+1} + \frac{2}{n+2} + \dots + \frac{n}{n+n} 
\end{equation}
$$

Fix $i$ between $1$ and $n$. Then you have:

$$ \frac{1}{i+1} + \frac{2}{i+2} + \dots + \frac{n}{i+n} = \sum_{j=1}^n \frac{j}{i+j}$$

Wolframalpha shows a "closed form" for this sum you can check at this [link](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum%20from%20j%3D1%20to%20n%20of%20j%2F%28i%2Bj%29&assumption=%22i%22%20-%3E%20%22Variable%22).